# Python Pandas Columns variables

Tags: python, csv, pandas, row, multiple-columns

Now my code is reading csv files. I have to do the next steps: if CP3 and CP4 have values then it's false if don't it's true and finally i need to keep values but i want it to return in boolean, if it's filled or not.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoy10.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])

df1.isnull().any()

CP4 = df1["CP4"]  # boolean
CP3 = df1["CP3"]  # boolean

for line in df1.iterrows():
    for row in df2.iterrows():

        if CP4 and CP3 is False:
```

Example:

```
CSV file = CP4, CP3
           3455, 543  CP4 and CP3 is False
           6473, null CP4 is False and CP3 is True
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data being handled and an example of the result you want?

Comment: This post is edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave you the result you want, you're free to store it wherever you find it appropriate:

```
res = ~(df1["CP4"] & df1["CP3"])
```

The "~" operator inverse the "&" (and) operator.